# How can i change between developer and distribution signing identites xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, code-signing-certificate

I have submitted an app to the app store. When i did this i was developing my app with a developer signing identity, then i created a distribution signing identity but i couldnt get xcode to use the distribution identity, so i deleted the developer identity and set only the distribution. Now i want to do things right, so i managed to import both identities in xcode and i can see them in xcode -> preferences -> view details 
[image]

What's next? how do i generate the binary to upload it to the itunes connect using the distribution identity? Any tips about uploading an app to the app store will be helpful.

Comment: download certificate from your account and install it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are confirmed the provisioning certificates are correct for both the development and production, you will have to set the correct **Code Signing Identity** and **Provisioning Profile** under the **Built Settings** for both **Project** and **Target**.

**Debug -> Development**

**Release -> Production**

This way, when you are developing and you run the project directly from XCode to your device, it will be using the development certificate. If you achieve it and extract to IPA. Then, it will be using the production certificate.

If you have a third certificate (Ad-Hoc Production) for beta testers, you may interchange that under the release with distribution certificate.

See the screen shot below.

[image: Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile]

Comment: This is what i needed to set both signing identities, also Vibha Singh helps me with the uploading of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps:

1. First create distribution provision certificate with valid bundle identifier on apple account(For this you should have the main distribution certificate).
2. Download and double click on certificate.
3. Then give bundle identifier name which you used while creating certificate in plist.
4. in Code signing select certificate of distribution
5. Clean build and archive it.
6. validate with iTunes and create ipa. then upload build using application loader on App Store.

Hope this will help. This is the common procedure of creating certificate, .ipa and uploading build.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to upload the app.